# Multi Select using angular schema forms

Tags: angularjs, multi-select, angular-schema-form

I am currently using multiselect checkbox in a dropdown using angular schema forms and my requirment say to disable some other control based on a value selected  But I am unable to bind any events to checking of a check box in multi select.
Can anyone Help me on this?

Comment: ng-change should be called every time you change value of your ng-model binded array. if not, $scope.$watchList() is like plan 'B', but try to do plan 'A' first with ng-change

Comment: This question could really do with a plunker, I assume the multiselect checkbox dropdown is an add-on?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to remove controls base on some condition of other controls. I made it by adding a condition on the form definition like:

"condition" : "model.nameOfField == 'valueOfField'"